# Not able to create subdir under dir in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I am able to create directory using the below command but not able to create the subdir under already created dir. May I know what could be the reason. I have setup hdfs on my mac in pseudo distributed mode and trying to create these directories. Any help would be appreciated.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /test/subdir
```

The above command doesn't create any sub directory however the below command creates a directory.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir test
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving it the parent creation flag.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /test/subdir
```

Answer (score 1):

To recursively create subdirectories inside parent directory, you have to provide `-p` option or else you can create one directory at a time.

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /test/subdir
```

will work in your case.